# Processor Underclock to 0.38Ghz if battery below 60%

Tags: laptop, cpu, battery, intel-core-i5

I've really got a very wierd issue with my laptop.
**Laptop Model:** Hp 15 AU006TX

**Processor:** Intel i5 6200U

**Operating System:** Windows 10 Home 1909

The issue that I'm facing is very wierd if my laptop is on charge the processor will run at full clock speed of 2.8Ghz. If I remove the charge from laptop and charge is above 60% the processor will continue to run at full clock speed of 2.8Ghz, as soon as the battery drops below 60% the process Underclock to 0.38Ghz instantaneously.

Even after putting the charge back, the processor continues to run at 0.38Ghz. The processor returns to normal clock speed only after restarting the laptop with charger plugged in or if the battery level has gone above 60% before the restart.

Whenever the processor clock speed drops I've checked the CPU temperature it's always below 50°C. So it's definitely not thermal throttling.

The only option I've to bring back the processor clock speed to normal is to use Throttle Stop software.

The Fan always runs at full speed irrespective of the CPU temperature. I've tried disabling Always On fan from BIOS but no luck.

Things I've tried so far.

- Putting laptop on high-performance mode
- Changing the power saving mode setting on battery
- Changing maximum and minimum state of the processor.
- Updating the BIOS and updating all the system software.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Power Options Advanced settings, under Processor power management, what the values for Minimum/Maximum processor state? How old is the battery?

Comment: I've set both to 99. I've recently replaced the battery it's lesser than 6 months old. I'm getting close to 3.5hours of backup.

Answer (score 3):

The battery seems to be in good shape and the power settings are excessive
but do not explain the problem.

The problem is probably with the motherboard. I can't help with a
hardware problem,
except if the computer is still under warranty, to suggest calling the
vendor's Support.

For software, you should assure that your BIOS and drivers are up to date.

You will find updates in the
[HP Software and drivers for HP Pavilion 15-au006tx](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-15-au000-notebook-pc-series/10862158/model/11543782).

You should especially take care to update the BIOS (carefully!) and the
Chipset driver.

Ensure also that you are using the latest Windows 10 version that Microsoft
suggests for your computer in *Settings > Update & Security*.
Don't force a later update if it is not listed there.

If newer software does not improve the problem, and if the laptop continues
to underclock to 0.38Ghz if the battery is below 60%, even during a heavy
workload, then the hardware is probably the cause.

Comment: Sometimes such an issue can be (partially) fixed with a bios update, in other cases not. Fujitsu H770 has similar issue: As soon it is taken from the charger the core-i7 goes from 3.4 GHz to 1.0 Ghz and disables the hyperthreading too. Took over 6 months and a lot of complaints before they finally issued a bios-update. The lower speed is now 1.4 Ghz. And that is all they can do about it. Apparantly the rest is hardwired in the motherboard.

Comment: How does the Throttle Stop fix the issue?